# how to save Checked value of checkbox in model class Flutter

Tags: android, flutter, dart

How to save checkbox checked value in model class so the box is remain selected when I come back to first from second page and also open a text filed on a last checkbox click?

```
Map<String, bool> values = {
    'Apple': false,
    'Banana': false,
    'Cherry': false,
    'Mango': false,
    'Orange': false,
  };
ListView(
            children: values.keys.map((String key) {
              return new CheckboxListTile(
                title: new Text(key),
                value: values[key],
                activeColor: Colors.pink,
                checkColor: Colors.white,
                onChanged: (bool value) {
                  setState(() {
                    values[key] = value;
                  });
                },
              );
            }).toList(),
          ),
```

Comment: Can you add some more code to see what you really need ?

Answer (score 1):

For accessing the state (or value) of a variable, across navigating between different widgets (or pages) in your app:

- Use state management:
  https://flutter.dev/docs/development/data-and-backend/state-mgmt/simple.

For storing values after closing and reopening your app, use a persistent storage method:

- Use shared preferences, for simpler forms of data, e.g. simple key-value pairs: https://flutter.dev/docs/cookbook/persistence/key-value.
- Use SQLite, for more extensive data, such as data tables: https://pub.dev/packages/sqflite.

There are more ways to do this, but these are the most common.

If you are new to Flutter I can imagine that these concepts may seem a little daunting. But they are really not as complex as they initially seem. And I can assure you that these concepts are crucially important to make any half-decent app.

Comment: can you reference or write example code??